# yarn start localhost:3000 not loading

Tags: wordpress-theming, yarnpkg

I am getting accustomed to [Sage 9](https://roots.io/sage-9/). I have everything set up but when I run `yarn start`, localhost:3000 opens in the browser and nothing loads. What should I be doing? Any tips would be great if you have experience working with Sage 9.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try http://localhost:5000/, it worked for me.